# Create items on List via GET

Tags: 2010, list, item

I am using SharePoint 2010, and I want to create Items in my List based on the url parameters(GET):

http://mysite/mylist/AllItems.aspx?code=123&user=xpto

In this example, my new item would be:
Code: 123
User: xpto

Is it possible to do this?

Can I have some code example please so I can try?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Doable. what you need to create is a javascript code that does the following:

1. Parse the URL and save code (into a variable) and user (into another variable)
   This link my help you get that https://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/how-can-i-get-query-string-values-in-javascript
2. Pass the 2 variables with the site URL and list name to the following function:

function createListItem(siteUrl,listName,code,user) {

```
var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext(siteUrl);
var oList = clientContext.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle(listName);

var itemCreateInfo = new SP.ListItemCreationInformation();
this.oListItem = oList.addItem(itemCreateInfo);

oListItem.set_item('code', code);
oListItem.set_item('user', user);

oListItem.update();

clientContext.load(oListItem);

clientContext.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQuerySucceeded), Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQueryFailed));
```

}

function onQuerySucceeded() {

```
alert('Item created: ' + oListItem.get_id());
```

}

function onQueryFailed(sender, args) {

```
alert('Request failed. ' + args.get_message() + '\n' + args.get_stackTrace());
```

}

Comment: does SP.ClientContext depends of some plugin?

Comment: you may need to Add ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded method before calling the function.

ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(createListItem, "sp.js");
or

SP.SOD.executeFunc('sp.js', 'SP.ClientContext', createListItem);

Comment: what is this 'sp.js' ?

Comment: SP.js is the JavaScript file used for the ECMA Client Object Model. This file is necessary to work with SharePoint Client Object Model.

Comment: So the value is always 'sp.js' ?